# Set event author with Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to set the author when adding an event to a Google Calendar with this code:

```
        CalendarService service = new CalendarService("TestApp");
        service.setUserCredentials("example@gmail.com", "1234");

        EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();

        // Set the title and content of the entry.
        entry.Title.Text = "Test";
        entry.Content.Content = "Test";

        // Not working
        AtomPerson author = new AtomPerson(AtomPersonType.Author);
        author.Name = "John Doe";
        author.Email = "john@example.com";
        entry.Authors.Add(author);

        When eventTime = new When(activity.Start, activity.End, activity.Start == activity.End ? true : false);
        entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

        Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

        // Send the request and receive the response:
        AtomEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
```

The event gets added with all the correct attributes except the author. The author remains the owner of the calendar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Calendar API documentation (http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingSingle):

> The server will insert author information based on the user that
>   submits the request (i.e. the user whose authentication token
>   accompanies the request).

It is not possible to set the value of the Author field when creating an event.